# Import MySQL data into an Orange ExampleTable

Tags: python, mysql, orange

I would like to import some MySQL data into an Orange ExampleTable and I really can't understand how to do it directly without converting the database format. I would like to connect to the server and read the data from it into an ExampleTable. Is it possible?

I've browsed through all the orange documentation and still did not find an example of how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [orngMySQL](http://orange.biolab.si/doc/modules/orngMySQL.htm) and the [orngSQL](http://orange.biolab.si/doc/modules/orngSQL.htm) python interfaces seem very close to what you want to achieve. Better than simply connecting to the whole database you can select only rows of interest, e.g.:

```
t = orngMySQL.Connect('localhost','root','','test')
data = t.query("SELECT * FROM busclass")
tree = orngTree.TreeLearner(data)
orngTree.printTxt(tree, nodeStr="%V (%1.0N)", leafStr="%V (%1.0N)")
```

Producing something like this:

```
root: late (12)
|    daytime=evening: on-time (4)
|    daytime=midday: late (3)
|    daytime=morning: late (5)
|    |    temp<7.500: on-time (1)
|    |    temp>=7.500: late (4)
```

This is as close as a direct interface as one can get IMHO.